# If statements working differently then expected

Tags: c#

This may or may not be a stupid question but why will the following 2 if statements result differently

lets say `k = "z";`

1. `if (!k=="x" || !k=="y")`

   `{`

   `//do something`

   `}`

2.

```
if (!(k=="x" || k=="y"))

{

//do something

}
```

In my mind both of these statements should hit //Do Something.... only the bottom one will actually be hit. which btw is the expected result.

Sorry again , however I can't wrap my ignorant mind around this.

Comment: The difference is that the second example compiles, while the first one doesn't...

Comment: Yea, sorry bad example, however on my side im checking if k.contains("") in which case you don't want to use = != ==...

Comment: They both compile just fine

Comment: The equality operator is `==`. The assignment operator is `=`. You've confused them, which is a common error.

Comment: Was a typo, thanks, prob don't deserve -3 ... back to the problem please...

Comment: No, the example as written does not compile. Gives error "Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'" If you're using .contains() in your code it probably does compile, but that's not at all equivalent to the sample you've given here.

Comment: Apart from the obvious == vs = you should also check [C# Operator Precedence and Associativity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Making the question clear and free of confusing typos is your responsibility, not ours.

Comment: Because `NOT A OR NOT B` != `NOT(A OR B)`

Comment: @BrianReischl if(!k.contains("x") || !k.contains("y")) { // do something} does NOT use == != = operators, therefore has everything to do with your first comment and compiles just fine.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to include what you are actually doing. We all know what `Contains` does.

Comment: Yes, but `if(!k.contains("x") || !k.contains("y"))` is not what you actually wrote in the question. The question has different, non-equivalent, non-compilable code. I apologize that I was too lazy to use my psychic abilities to read the code that you thought about but did not actually post, I'll try harder next time. But if you tried harder instead, you might not get so many downvotes on your next question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is "why is `(NOT X) OR (NOT Y)` different from `NOT(X OR Y)`?"

`NOT(X OR Y)` is false if either X or Y is true, and true otherwise.

`(NOT X) OR (NOT Y)` is false if both X and Y are true, and true otherwise.

"either X or Y is true" and "both X and Y are true" are different.

Here is a good technique when you are confused: draw a truth table:

```
X    Y    NOT X    NOT Y    X OR Y    (NOT X) OR (NOT Y)   NOT(X OR Y)
T    T     F         F       T                F                F
T    F     F         T       T                T                F
F    T     T         F       T                T                F
F    F     T         T       F                T                T
```

Now is it clear that they are different?

If you now draw the truth table for `NOT(X AND Y)` you'll see that it is the same as `(NOT X) OR (NOT Y)`, so those two expressions are equivalent.

And if you draw the truth table for `(NOT X) AND (NOT Y)` you'll see that it is the same as `NOT(X OR Y)`. Again, those two expressions are equivalent.

Make sure that's clear.

Now, you have a bigger problem here:

```
k != "x" || k != "y"
```

This predicate cannot be anything but true. Suppose k is "x". Then it is clearly not "y", so the predicate is true. Suppose k is "y". Then it is clearly not "x", so the predicate is true. Suppose k is any other value. Then it is clearly neither "x" nor "y", so the predicate is true. Therefore no matter what, this is vacuously true.  `(NOT X) OR (NOT Y)` does *not* mean "neither X nor Y".

Answer (score 7):

This is because you are miss-understanding logical expression evaluation.  See the wikipedia page for [DeMorgans Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for further reading but the gist of what you need is this bit...

`!(A || B)` is the same as `!A && !B`

This is not really a stupid question... it's a very easy logic error to make and fairly common as well.

For completeness I should add the following as well...

`!A || !B` is the same as `!(A && B)`